# Regex: Capturing first occurrence before lookahead

Tags: regex

I'm trying to capture the urls before a particular word. The only trouble is that the word could also be part of the domain.

Examples: (i'm trying to capture everything before dinner)

```
https://breakfast.example.com/lunch/dinner/

https://breakfast.example.brunch.com:8080/lunch/dinner

http://dinnerdemo.example.com/dinner/
```

I am able to use:

```
^(.*://.*/)(?=dinner/?)
```

The trouble I am having is the lookahead doesn't appear to by lazy enough
So the following is failing:

```
https://breakfast.example.com/lunch/dinner/login.html?returnURL=https://breakfast.example.com/lunch/dinner/
```

as it captures:

```
https://breakfast.example.com/lunch/dinner/login.html?returnURL=https://breakfast.example.com/lunch/
```

I'm both failing to understand why and how to fix my regex.
Perhaps I'm on the wrong track but how can I capture all my examples?

Comment: What language do you use?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use some laziness:

```
^(.*?:\/\/).*?/(?=dinner/?)
```

[Live demo](http://www.regexr.com/392b3)

By using a `.*` in the middle of your regex you ate everything until the last colon, where it found a match.

`.*` in the middle of a regex, by the way, is very bad practice.  It can cause horrendous backtracking performance degradation in long strings.  `.*?` is better, since it is reluctant rather than greedy.

Answer (score 4):

The lookahead doesn't have to be lazy or not, the lookahead is only a check and in your case with a quasi-fixed string.

What you need to make lazy is obviously the subpattern before the lookahead.

```
^https?:\/\/(?:[^\/]+\/)*?(?=dinner(?:\/|$))
```

Note: `(?:/|$)` is like a boundary that ensures the word "dinner" is followed by a slash or the end of the string.

Answer (score 1):

You're primary flaw is using greedy matching `.*` versus non-greedy `.*?`.

The following performs the matching that you desire using perl, but the regex could easily be applied in any language.  Note the use of word boundaries around dinner, which might or might not be what you want:

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;

while (<DATA>) {
    if (m{^(.*?://.*?/.*?)(?=\bdinner\b)}) {
        print $1, "\n";
    }
}

__DATA__
https://breakfast.example.com/lunch/dinner/
https://breakfast.example.brunch.com:8080/lunch/dinner
http://dinnerdemo.example.com/dinner/
```

Outputs:

```
https://breakfast.example.com/lunch/
https://breakfast.example.brunch.com:8080/lunch/
http://dinnerdemo.example.com/
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way as well.

```
 # Multi-line optional
 # ^(?:(?!://).)*://[^?/\r\n]+/(?:(?!dinner)[^?/\r\n]+/)*(?=dinner)


 ^                    # BOL
 (?:
      (?! :// )
      . 
 )*
 ://
 [^?/\r\n]+           # Domain
 /     
 (?:
      (?! dinner )    # Dirs ?
      [^?/\r\n]+ 
      /          
 )*
 (?= dinner )
```

`https://breakfast.example.com/lunch/`dinner/

`https://breakfast.example.brunch.com:8080/lunch/`dinner

`http://dinnerdemo.example.com/`dinner/

`https://breakfast.example.com/lunch/`dinner/login.html?returnURL=https://breakfast.example.com/lunch/dinner/

Answer (score 0):

Using python 3.7

```
import re
s = '''
https://breakfast.example.com/lunch/dinner/
https://breakfast.example.brunch.com:8080/lunch/dinner
http://dinnerdemo.example.com/dinner/
'''
pat = re.compile(r'.*(?=dinner)', re.M)
mo = re.findall(pat, s)
for line in mo:
    print(line, end=' ')
```

Print Output:

```
https://breakfast.example.com/lunch/
https://breakfast.example.brunch.com:8080/lunch/
http://dinnerdemo.example.com/
```